# Next.js 14 { cache: 'no-store' } not fetching latest data from sanity.io and showing deleted/old posts

Tags: next.js, caching, sanity

I'm running into an issue with the caching behavior of Next.js when using the { cache: 'no-store' } option in the fetch function. According to the Next.js documentation, this option should fetch data dynamically on every request and bypass the cache.

However, in my case, when I use { cache: 'no-store' }, it doesn't fetch the latest data from my Sanity CMS. Instead, it shows deleted posts and doesn't display newly created posts. This is the code I'm using:

```
const fetchPosts = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post"] | order(publishedAt desc){
    title,
    slug,
    publishedAt,
    mainImage {
      asset->{
        _id,
        url
      },
      alt
    },
    author->{
      name
    }
  }`;

  try {
    const posts = await client.fetch(query, { cache: 'no-store' });
    console.log("Posts fetched:", posts);
    return posts;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Sanity fetch error:", error);
    return [];
  }
};
```

On the other hand, when I use { next: { revalidate: 3600 } }, it fetches the latest data as expected.

I've tried restarting the development server, clearing caches, and inspecting the response headers. I've also tried `useCdn = true` and `useCdn = false` but the issue persists.

Can anyone explain why { cache: 'no-store' } isn't working as expected and showing me the latest data?